# How To Print Any Document/Image To File?

Tags: windows, images, printing

I want to print .TXT, .RTF, .DOC, .PDF, .HTML, etc. to file so the file will be in graphical format and will be able to be read by any imaging program (Windows Paint, Photoshop etc.).

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This virtual printer driver takes print requests and outputs to a variety of common formats, well worth a look:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/imageprinter/

Original link is dead; from archive:  [archived link](https://archive.is/bXBb)

Comment: This is 32 bit only. The pro version is not free.

Answer (score 0):

You could press the prtscr (or whatever the print screen button is called and then paste it into paint and save. (but that depends on the document size). But for small documents it could work.

Comment: You will only get monitor's DPI in this case.

Comment: That is true however I wasn't sure but considering he wants to open a document in paint or Photoshop I thought he'd only want a view able section not the whole document. Maybe open the PDF in Google Chrome and try to use the awesome screenshot extension and see how that works.