# How can I print to a .doc file?

Tags: printing, rtf, docx

I've used programs that add a PDF Printer to the print menu allowing me to output my printed document into a PDF document.  I'd like to do the same thing but output to a .doc, docx or .rtf format.

I'm already able to print to PDF or XPS and convert it to a Word document but I want a one step option.  To be clear I am only interested in using the print menu to output to an editable doc/rtf file. How can I accomplish this?

I'm using Microsoft Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- [LeadTools Eprinter:](http://www.eprintdriver.com/ePrintFilePrinter.html)

> **With LEADTOOLS ePrint you can print your documents, spreadsheets,
>   brochures, anything that can be printed, to any of over 150 file
>   formats (PDF, DOC, TIFF, JPEG, BMP and more).** This can be done with or
>   without printing to a paper printer. It's as easy as printing a file
>   from any of your Windows applications!
>
> LEADTOOLS ePrint installs as a printer driver therefore allowing you
>   to "print" your file to the many image and document file formats
>   offered by ePrint. Not only can you print and save your file, but you
>   can use LEADTOOLS ePrint to email your print job instead of faxing it,
>   so the recipient can enjoy the quality of a color image. Print,
>   convert, save and email all at the same time!

Comment: I havent tried this product, but in my experience programs that try to print to document formats really mess up the formatting.  You might spend more time fixing the document than it would take to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://code-industry.net/imageprinterpro/ I found only a paid version, half the price of LeadTools

Duplicate : [How To Print Any Document/Image To File?](https://superuser.com/questions/305979/how-to-print-any-document-image-to-file)

Comment: OP wants to convert files to .doc format, not image formats. This answer is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tool which is free to print 2 pages with. It's not bad but the fonts come out look like monospaced ones:

http://www.bullzip.com/products/ptw/info.php